# SQL Compare a field that is being updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update, case

I have the following query:

```
UPDATE #Temp_SessionItem SET [Status] = 
    CASE
        WHEN ([AddressFK] IS NULL OR [StatusFK] IS NULL) AND [Status] = 1
            THEN 3
        WHEN [AddressFK] IS NOT NULL AND [StatusFK] IS NOT NULL AND [Status] = 1
            THEN 2
    END
```

The problem is that when it's executed it doesn't actually give me the result I am expecting. i.e. it doesn't set the value of [`Status`] field to 3 in case [`AddressFK`] or [`StatusFK`] is `NULL`. Instead, it just tries to add `NULL` to Status when it should add 3.

If I remove the `AND [Status] = 1` part of the expression it does return 3 but then it updates also the values that are not `[Status] = 1`.

Is there anything obvious that I'm missing here?

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

**EDIT:**

After Royi Namir pointed out to me I realized that the problem must be further down the stored procedure that this query is being executed in. Specifically, #Temp_SessionItem is just a temporary table. After the upper mentioned query I'm trying to update the original table with the following query:

```
--  update the status of the original session item table
    UPDATE UploadSessionItem SET [Status] = T.[Status]
    FROM #Temp_SessionItem AS T
    WHERE UploadSessionItem.UploadSessionItemId  = T.ID
```

..which is obviously not working since all the [`Status`] items there are still 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to affect rows with a current `STATUS` of `1`, you need a `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE #Temp_SessionItem SET [Status] = 
    CASE
        WHEN ([AddressFK] IS NULL OR [StatusFK] IS NULL)
            THEN 3
        WHEN [AddressFK] IS NOT NULL AND [StatusFK] IS NOT NULL
            THEN 2
    END
WHERE [Status] = 1
```

---

The update you've shown works fine:

```
create table UploadSessionItem(UploadSessionItemID int,Status int)
insert into UploadSessionItem
select 1,1 union all select 2,2
create table #Temp_SessionItem (ID int,Status int)
insert into #Temp_SessionItem select 1,4
--Your UPDATE:
UPDATE UploadSessionItem SET [Status] = T.[Status]
    FROM #Temp_SessionItem AS T
    WHERE UploadSessionItem.UploadSessionItemId  = T.ID
--
select * from UploadSessionItem
```

Result:

```
UploadSessionItemID Status
1                   4
2                   2
```

So if the problem *is* elsewhere, it's not in a code sample you've shown us yet.

Answer (score 2):

@bojanskr  , either both [AddressFK] & [StatusFK]  are not null , or your staus!=1

what is the value of status before updating ? what kind of type he is ?

**paste** the result from this query here :

```
  select case when [AddressFK] IS NULL then 'AddressFKnull' else 'AddressFKNOTnull' end,
    case when [StatusFK] IS NULL then 'StatusFKnull' else 'StatusFKNOTnull' end , Status
    from  #Temp_SessionItem
```

Comment: Before updating the status is 1, that is why after processing it should be set to 3 or 2. Status is type smallint

Comment: nullable ? what value does he have before updting ?

Comment: No, it's not nullable. And before the updating it has value 1

Comment: Since the problem is oviosly somewhere else, i will update my question

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a default case, so you get NULL when neither of those conditions are true. You could rewrite it like this:

```
UPDATE #Temp_SessionItem SET [Status] = 
  CASE
    WHEN ([AddressFK] IS NULL OR [StatusFK] IS NULL)
        THEN 3
    ELSE 2
  END
WHERE [Status] = 1
```